# Printing with zebra MZ220 from android

Tags: android

What i´m trying to do is to print a label with zebra mz220 using the information I have in my SQLite database, but I don´t know how to fill in the label using strings. Here is my code so far

---

case R.id.bprint:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    // Instantiate connection for given Bluetooth® MAC Address.
                    ZebraPrinterConnection thePrinterConn = new BluetoothPrinterConnection("00:22:58:3C:9F:0B");

                    // Initialize 
                    Looper.prepare();

                    // Open the connection - physical connection is established here.
                    thePrinterConn.open();



                    // here it should fill in the label but it doesn't =(
                    thePrinterConn.write("Input (ENCODING.LBL):! 0 200 200 200 1 ENCODING UTF-8 TEXT 0 20 30 r/n/ PRINTr/n/".getBytes());



                    //Make sure the data got to the printer before closing the connection
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                    // Close the connection to release resources.
                    thePrinterConn.close();

                    Looper.myLooper().quit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Handle communications error here
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }).start();

            break;

    case R.id.spb:

        startActivity(new Intent(this, Barcode.class));

        break;
```

please help, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What did you try so far? I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks appropriate, but unfortunately your comment "I don't know how to fill in the label using strings" isn't very clear. What is the outcome when you run your code? What are you trying to achieve? As an example, you can send the following data to the printer in your 'write' call. Assuming your printer is in CPCL mode:

```
thePrinterConn.write("! 0 200 200 210 1\r\nTEXT 4 0 30 30 Hello world\r\nFORM\r\nPRINT\r\n" .getBytes());
```

CPCL manual section 2 page 3: support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've already read the cpcl manual, i´ll try to explain my self better, in my first two activities are to gather information and I send it to a sqlite database, with this info I want to print a ticket, any idea?. thanks for your help